# ODI-can loadplans have Marker code like scenarios

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

iam new to ODI. we use marker group and marker object code to select some scenario.is it possible to add markers to load plans

howmany ways we can create loadplans and how can we export .please provide me some videos on it

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please note that Stack Overflow is not made to ask for tutorial, video or book recommendation. Please use Stack Overflow to get help with code and see [On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)